# In a functional programming what would you call this sort of operation?

Tags: functional-programming

In a functional programming what would you call this sort of operation?

```
function(f,vargs){ //variable count of arguments
   return function(){
       return f(vargs)
   }
}
```

I think this is Currying, but I had the impression that currying is the term when we bind a single argument not several arguments. Or perhaps this is a delay, not really sure...

Comment: @pavium, yeah it might be a bit confusing at first sight, but it's not obfuscation :)

Comment: Yes, I was being ironic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apply` is the correct term -- for instance, Python had an equivalent [`apply`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#apply) (that is now deprecated).

See also partial application [in Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Partial_application) or [in Javascript](http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/).  If partial application uses *some* of the arguments of the function, then it follows that *full* application, or just application, must use *all* of the arguments, like you did above.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's called function application.

Remember that in a functional paradigm,

```
function(){
    return f(vargs)
}
```

being a function with no arguments, is roughly the equivalent of a procedural-programming variable containing the result of `f(vargs)`.

Answer (score 2):

I am of the understanding that currying is the act of partially applying functions and returning a function that matches the signature of the original function minus the applied arguments.

Take a look at this article - [The Art of Currying](http://diditwith.net/2007/08/15/TheArtOfCurrying.aspx)

This looks like a [Higher Order function](http://diditwith.net/2007/06/21/AHigherCalling.aspx)

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure if it's one argument at a time or not.

Comment: I don't think that it has to be one argument to be a curried function, just not all arguments :)

Answer (score 1):

I would call is constructing a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 0):

```
function(f, args) {
    return (
        function() { return f(vargs) }
      )
 }
```

The outer function takes *f* and *args*, what it returns is an anonymous function that only returns `f(args)`, where *f* and *vargs* are arguments of the outer function.

In *Mathematica* for example you can write it as `F[f_, args___] := f[args]&`.  Because the returned anonymous function is a constant function (not accepting any argument), you may also write it as `F[f_, args___] := f[args]`, omitting the last `&`.

Comment: Do you know the name used in Mathematica for this sort of thing?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no standard name for the whole operation, which takes _f_ and _args_ as arguments, and returns a constant function whose value is obtained by applying _f_ to _args_.